# Где продолжить обучение школьнику-программисту(Москва)?

Tags: php, javascript, c++, c

Здравствуйте!

Предрассказ, что б вы могли мне адекватно помочь:
Меня зовут Влад, мне 15 лет, живу в Москве,учусь в 9 классе, хочу стать программистом, пока знаю html css javascript jQuery(+UI) и PHP.

Сейчас хожу на курсы и изучаю СИ, затем хочу плотно заняться С++ и потом object-c.
Я довольно умный :), хочу стать хорошим, широко-профильным  программистом(да я понимаю, что многие это отвергают, но я не вплане всё знать, а быть спецом в какой-то области но не узким).

В школе учусь нормально, только одна тройка  - по русскому.
1.Подскажите пожалуйста, куда пойти учиться после 9 класса?
2.На кого лучше(профессия)?
3.Посоветуйте хорошие техникумы и колледжи.

Спасибо!

**PS Прошу помочь, и подойти к теме серьезно!**

Comment: Мы тут все довольно умные :-D

Куда именно вам идти не скажу, т.к. далекот Москвы, но от себя посоветую побольше заниматься самообразованием, ни в каком ВУЗе вам не дадут достаточно знаний, дадут только нужный минимум, остальное нужно будет все равно постигать самому. 

Ну а хорошим специалистом в какой-то из областей вы станете уже в процессе профессиональной разработки.

Comment: Так я и занимаюсь самообразованием.

Comment: Не ясна логика - знаешь все по веб и тут такой скачок - C, C++... Причем, по факту, опыта реальной разработки - нет, собственно вопрос: зачем было учить html, css, js, php?

Ну и я вам сразу напишу откровенно - из перечисленного выше, вы, максимум, знаете html и css. Остальное **по определению** вы **знать** в 15 лет не можете (развичто вы не занимались вебом лет с 12и)

Самая главная ваша проблема что вы не знаете чего вы хотите, решите ее сначала, потом этот вопрос отпадет сам

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь!
1)Я веб технологие изучал, по совету дяди.
2)C/c++ мне нужен для разработки под Windows. И я этому учусь. 
3)Я знаю чего я хочу и что меня интересует, а именно:
    1.Разработка сайтов.
    2.Разработка для мобильных платформ(IOS и WP).
    3.Разработка программ под Windows(программы анализоторы ПС по API, т.е. сео софт)

Comment: О этот юношеский максимализм :D

Выберите сначала что нибудь одно, достигните в этом нормального уровня мастерства, потом уже можете переходить к чему-то другому.
****
"Я веб технологи**е** изучал, по совету дяди". Это не говорит о том что вы знаете все что вы написали выше на нормальном уровне.
****
Вообще лучший совет для тебя сейчас, повторюсь - определиться с тем чего именно ты хочешь, сейчас ты хочешь всего и понемногу, а одной попой, как известно...

И напоследок: C/c++ мне нужен для разработки под Windows... Для разработки **чего именно?** У вас есть реальная восстребованая задача?

Comment: Да, есть программа в голове. Сейчас её пытаюсь реализовать.
Впринципе, для меня важен пункт 1 и 2.

Comment: Ну вот - идите в 10-11 классы и реализовывайте себе, потом пойдете в ВУЗ (ну или создадите второй майкрософт, это как получится xD)

И, все-же, считаю что с подходом "всего понемногу" далеко не продвинутся. Вернее можно, но для этого нужно  заниматся этим **целыми днями**, можете мне поверить это не так просто как может показаться на первый взгляд.

В любом случае удачи.

Comment: Если пытаетесь произвести впечатление «довольно умного» человека, то старайтесь хотя бы писать грамотно. По поводу вопроса: языки — дело наживное, а вот адекватность в компьютерных технологиях надо изучать. А для этого как минимум математика какая-никакая да нужна. Будет математическая база и опыт в конкретной области — будет и адекватность. А от языков абстрагироваться надо. Кто сказал, что через пару лет php не умрёт, и все веб-девелоперы не начнут писать на Scala? Ну это я так.

Comment: PHP не умрет никогда :D

Comment: "Никогда" - это слишком сильно сказано. Но на наш век, думаю, хватит.

Comment: Как не прискорбно :D

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что холивар.

Comment: @Suvitruf, спустя 3 года, Ваше замечание очень важно. Оно может кардинально изменить жизньТС.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК если вопрос старый, это не значит, что не нужно чистить SO от него.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

После 9 класса лучше идти в 10 класс. Потом на выбор -  в Москве ВУЗов по информатике много.

Comment: Зачем 2 года терять? 
А с вузом, я решил в МГУ идти. Родители поддержали.

Comment: Почему терять? Кто мешает сейчас изучать информатику? Я, честно говоря, не понимаю, чему учат в этих техникумах по информатике. 

Если очень хочется, иди в какую-нибудь физматшколу.

Comment: В ВУЗах толкового мало... в техникумах - еще меньше

Comment: Главное, что нужно и можно ожидать от хорошего ВУЗа - это основательная математическая подготовка и глубокие теоретические знания в информатике.   И то, и другое очень даже пригодятся, если есть желание расти. Ну и общее образование, кругозор и т.д. Языки дают только самые основы, да иначе и невозможно. В программировании без самообразования никак, особенно учитывая объем знаний и темп их развития. А техникум, по-моему, полный бред. Лучше найти хорошую школу, с хорошим общим образованием, хорошим английским языком, хорошей физикой и математикой. И готовиться в ВУЗ.

Comment: ВУЗ лишь предлагает изучить то что вы написали. Но большая половина этого не знает. + в ВУЗах учат огромному множеству неактуальной, лишней информации. В общем случае ВУЗ лишь помогает найти первую работу и предлагает изучить что-либо. Что касается техникума - ничего плохого тоже не вижу. У техникума есть очень большой + по сравнению с ВУЗом - быстрый старт(быстро можно найти работу)

Вопрос в другом - нужно ли все это? У меня есть знакомые, сейчас на последнем курсе, учатся на программистов. Дубы-дубами =\

ИМХО ВУЗ и техникум - помошники, но не необходимость

Comment: Если не прилагать личных усилий, то никакой самый лучший универ не поможет.

Comment: Я именно это и имел введу =)

Comment: Так это любого образования касается. А информатики - особенно. В любом вузе могут дать только основы и привить культуру мысли.

Comment: Попытатся дать основы и попытатся привить культуру мысли (не факт что правильную кстати!!!)

Comment: Ну так нужно хороший вуз выбирать. И не факт, что сам правильную приобретешь.

Comment: Естественно не факт, но в ВУЗах чаще всего обучают old-school'ьному мышлению, что в современных реалиях IT довольно часто является неприменимым.

Например всех моих знакомых в ВУЗе научили тому, что linux устарел и винда всему голова, самое печальное что все из них свято в это верят =\

Comment: Насколько я знаю, на ВМК МГУ очень серьезно преподают программирование в Юникс (не только Линукс), и многие преподы хорошие спецы как раз в юниксовых системах. А если самому не работать, не программиоровать и не думать, то хорошим прогером никогда не станешь.

Answer (score 1):

хоть и холивар ,но вставлю свои 5 копеек, так как сам с такими проблемами в 9ом классе сталкивался =)
вначале про колледжвуз
я после 9ого пошел в лицей при бауманке (лицей 1580 на чертановской). Это однозначно лучше колледжей.Если интересно, то могу более подробно рассказать,но туда надо экзамены сдавать =) Про сунц при мгу не знаю....одного поля ягоды, они не лучше наших на олимпиадах выступали. Обучаться программированию надо самостоятельно это однозначно, так что в в колледжевузе тебе надо математику подтягивать.
Начет вуза.
В бауманку однозначно не иди. Сам закончил, сам знаю - делать там нечего =) на мех.мат мгу тож не стоит, будешь только теориями заниматься. ВМК  самое оптимальное.
Весь 11 класс будешь парится насчет физики и математики уровня экзамена. так что используй 10ый класс с толком =)
Колледж это пустая трата времени. Мало того что будешь с баранами учиться, так еще и сама подготовка будет на нуле.
Про самоподготовку.
Можно мноооого путей выбрать. исходя из того что у тебя сейчас есть и что ты задаешь этот вопрос вот я бы тебе порекомендовал онлайн университет [Интуит](http://www.intuit.ru/) . Там реально ооооочень грамотный материал.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно мне с тобой связаться?

Comment: а там в контактной инфе нет мыла? jobstas@gmail.com =) а че, надо учить подрастающее поколение ))))

Comment: Видал я ВМК-шных программистов.. ИМХО - самые толковые программеры - как раз после мехмата. Потому как знают теорию, и понимают не только как, но и почему.

Comment: холивар))))

Answer (score 0):

Я б посоветовал МГУ довольно серьезный вуз. А так то согласен с постом выше, нет не чего лучше само обучения. Вузы учат как учится, а знания приходят по мере желания

Comment: приходят по мере желания??? Мечтай, нифига не делай и будет тебе счастье? xD

Comment: Может есть техником по Информатике при МГУ?

Comment: Не знаю техникумов я из Питера. 

>Мечтай, нифига не делай и будет тебе счастье? xD
как это понимать?я всю свою жизнь чего то делаю, если у человека нет желания получать знания ни один вуз не поможет.

Comment: Это я у вас хотел спросить - как это понимать, вы сами написали так какбудто ВУЗ учит человека а не человек учится в ВУЗе

Answer (score 0):

Привет.
Если ты считаешь себя умным, то прости зачем тебе идти в колледж?
Тебя не ждут никакое будущее. 
Ты бы не хотел заниматься олимпиадным программированием? Это на самом деле интересно, есть олимпиады для школьников, летние компьютерные школы и т.п.
Если хочешь быть крутым программистом то нужно идти в МГУ на ВМК или в СПБГУ или в МФТИ на ФИВТ.
сейчас есть математические школы СУНЦ МГУ (туда набор в 10 класс), Лицей Вторая школа, 179, 57. Во всех этих школах есть наборы в 8-9. В 10 ест в СУНЦ и в Л2Ш. Там учат программированию-математике. У них все поступают в МГУ, МФТИ и т.п.
Учасвствуют в олимпиадах. Дерзай :)

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите пожалуйста, на ВМК в МГУ какие языки изучают?

Comment: По поводу СУНЦ МГУ - мне через всю Москву туда ехать.

Comment: Знаю, что учат Паскаль (традиция), С/С++, вроде как shell, немного php. Вроде как основы Джавы. Да это и не важно. Главное, какие теоретические знания дают. А язык можно и самому выучить при наличии хорошей базы.

Answer (score 0):

> Да, есть программа в голове. Сейчас её пытаюсь реализовать.

Что за программа? Сразу говорю: графический интерфейс удобнее всего делать на C#. 3D-графику - на C++. Если программа не требует высокой производительности, советую изучать C#. В C++ очень много разных подвохов, из-за которых на форумах задают кучу вопросов. По C# вопросов возникает в десятки раз меньше.

Сам я начал изучать C++ самостоятельно тоже в 15 лет по книге. Перелез на C++ с Game maker'а, потому что захотел делать 3D игры. Начал писать движок через 1,5 месяца после начала изучения. Всё ещё пишу (2 года). Уже хорошо знаю язык. Посвящаю программированию практически всё своё свободное время.
 Сейчас учусь в 11-м классе.

Так что, советую изучить самостоятельно язык и начать писать свою программу. Когда делаешь свой проект, знания закрепляются на практике.

Comment: Спасибо. Программа - так фигня, анализ различный Сео данных.

Answer (score 0):

Вставал перед таким-же вопросом, в 9том классе, в результате пошёл в 10тый но занялся само-обучением, в результате свалил с десятого класа через 1.5 месяца и вполотную начал заниматся само обучением, ищя свой пусть. Поже начал заниматся фриленсингом, а потом пришла своя идея и свой проект(не буду уточнять суть и язык), чейчас мне 18 и последние пол года проект кормит по 2к$ в месяц, и вод идти-ли на учёбу дальше.

Comment: >Поже начал заниматся фриленсингом, а потом пришла своя идея и свой проект(не буду уточнять суть и язык)

 Может уточнишь? Интересно.

Comment: У меня в голове тоже есть проекты, которые будут приносить более 2К/$ в месяц. Вот и занимаюсь их реализацией.

Comment: фриленсинг? просвети, что это?

Comment: GLmonster, Конкретно говорить о сути проекта не буду, ибо нехочу пропогондировать какуюто определёную отрась програмирования.
Моуг сказать что проект состоит из C#-C++ пользовательского интерфейса, и и серверной части (JAVA-MySQL и некоторые вкусности Linux) и разумеется WEB сайт. 
И помоему, самое важное для создание своего проекта это обязательно серверная часть, то-есть проект должен использовать или быть привязан к вашему серверу, иначе его просто могут украсть у вас, и даже нестоит брать во внимание обфускацию чего-либо.

Elime - http://www.free-lance.ru/

Comment: ВладиславМСК, в общем что пока выходит, по решению вашего вопроса, учиться что-бы потом работать на кокого-то дядю, пахать и ничего не получить, или учится и заняться своим проектом, и нужна-ли учёба для открытия своего проекта...
В общемя, я как-то повёл тему беседы в противоположную от выбора места учёбы, сторону

Comment: @dezmail, так может все-таки фриланс, а не фриленс ?

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: >И помоему, самое важное для создание своего проекта это обязательно серверная часть, то-есть проект должен использовать или быть привязан к вашему серверу, иначе его просто могут у вас украсть, и даже нестоит брать во внимание обфускацию чего-либо.

 Как украсть? Я же не буду распространять исходный код. Если писать не под .NET, то декомпилировать не смогут. Взломать и так всё могут, никакие защиты не защитят.

Comment: @GLmonster, он наверное имел в виду порядочность хостера.

Answer (score 0):

Влад, честно, поступай туда - куда сможешь. Основная цель ВУЗА (высшего учебного заведения) научить тебя самостоятельной работе с материалом, т.е. чтобы ты мог самообучаться. Всё остальному ты научшися по ходу процесса обучения, если будешь прилагать для этого усилия.

Comment: Я поступать буду в МГУ. ЭТО ТОЧНО безбедное существование.

Comment: А чем МФТИ (или как он сейчас называется ?) хуже ?

Comment: Влад, с такими знаниями в 15 лет про МГУ можно в приниципе забыть. Хотя если у родителей есть деньги это не проблема. :)

Comment: ПОЧЕМУ? АРГУМЕНТИРУЙТЕ!

Comment: В 15 лет я тоже не особенно что знал. 1 года в 11 классе мне хватило для подготовки в МГУ. Поступил с первого раза без блата и взяток.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как вы готовились? Я просто тоже так хочу :).

Comment: Это было, когда Вас еще не было. В 1991 году. Ходил на какие-то там курсы (лекции читали) + заочные курсы при МГУ. Потом в мае еще какие ускоренные курсы по математике. Я на биофак поступал. Главное мотивация и самообразование.

Answer (score 0):

думаю с таким мышлением лучше пойти на фил.фак там любят размышлять, там каждый умный,

> а быть спецом в какой-то области но
> не узким

пипец звучит ток как! Программисты на то и специализируются в разных направлениях, уверяю  тебя ты не станешь ни хорошим web ни хорошим системным программистом, если вот так вот тебя бросает от одного к другому.

Так что либо сразу бросить все на корню, либо заняться только одним и там продвигаться.

```
пока знаю html css javascript jQuery(+UI) и PHP.
```

на уровне чего? чтения? я могу, поверь, написать намного больше, особенно того что просто когда-то увидел, но ни разу не пользовался. в твоём списке по минимуму не хватает MySql БД, так что учи MySql и через год полтора мы вернемся к твоему вопросу куда тебе поступать в Мск.

Comment: Да, я согласен, мой уровень нельзя сравнить с вашим. Но я реально все из перечисленного знаю на уровне любителя, а СИ я вообще ходил учить на курсы при МГТУ Баумана, сейчас кернигана штудирую, что б свою программу написать. 
Кстате, я MySQL не знаю, я в php использую БД SQLite.

Comment: не надо длать градацию на "нас" и "вас", она довольно условна. суть учебы в школе институте в том чтобы научить тебя учится (в том числе и на собственном опыте), не учить что-то конкретное (типа сколько хромосом у букашки), а просто научится самому процесу обучения. + ты должен уметь (читай: научится или знать где искать) находить нужную тебе информацию. 
если школа сдерживает твое развитие то не надо пугатся. с другой стороны сейчас век интернет технологий, для того чтоб устроится учеником программиста необязательно даже выходить из дому

Comment: ^^ продолжение: не забывай что обучение это еще то время которое выделено тебе для того чтоб ты созрел как личность и научился принимать правильные решения. когда ты лет через 5 начнешь зарабатывать себе на жизнь, а лет через 10 будешь по 10-15 часов тратить на работу, ты скорее за все ты поймешь что это не главное в жизни.
тянет к институту? много знаешь? ты лучше всех в своей школе? езжай на олимпиады, там ты поймешь что тебе еще есть куда развиватся. кроме олимпиад в школе можно еще участвовать в олимпиадах в тех же институтах.
в институт можно даже поступить заочно если очень хочется :)